# How to get wiki and profile manager to run on different port

Tags: macos, server.app, network, ssl

Currently the wiki and the profile manager runs on port `443` (ssl).

We have other services using port 443 on our network, and therefore I cannot port forward that port to my Lion Server.

How can I get the wiki and the profile manager to run on a port other than port 443?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I decided to research "Apache" without specifying "OS X" in my research.

I found that you can change the listen port in a conf file

```
$ mdfind httpd-ssl.conf

    # Found
    # /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-ssl.conf

$ cd /private/etc/apache2.extra
$ sudo nano httpd-ssl.conf

    # ctrl + w
    # 443

    # Change Listen 443 to Listen 4444
    # ctrl + o
    # ctrl + x
```

*note: enabling `root` would allow you to listen on port `444`*

Answer (score 0):

This is only possible in Snow Leopard server and not Lion Server (I think).

Comment: It may only be possible via a GUI on Snow Leopard, but I'm fairly confident that changes can be made via Terminal since both OS's use Apache to serve web.

Comment: I can `sudo nano httpd.conf` and change the default listen port for `80` but I can't find the directive for `443`.

Comment: found it - see my answer.